# Cannot test angular pipe with injected angularjs service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-hybrid

AngularJS Service:

```
app.service('NameService', function() {
  this.name = function (name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }
});
```

Angular Upgrade:

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
export const NameService = new InjectionToken<any>('NameService');

export function nameServiceFactory(i: any): any {
  return i.get('NameService');
}
export const nameServiceProvider = {
  provide: NameService,
  useFactory: nameServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};
```

Now I can use that service in am Angular component or pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'name',
  pure: false
})
export class NamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(@Inject(NameService) private nameService: any) { }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    // can use this.nameService here
  }
}
```

I am running into problems with testing this pipe.

```
describe('NamePipe', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [nameServiceProvider],
      declarations: [NamePipe]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('create an instance', () => {
    const service: any = TestBed.get(NameService);
    const pipe = new NamePipe(service);
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This throws the following error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector!

I have tried looking here https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/testing/ at **createAngularJSTestingModule** and **createAngularTestingModule**  without any luck.

As soon as I pull in my AngularJS module into the test I get errors that there is no loader to handle .html file types that live in the angularJS module.

How do I inject an Upgraded AngularJS service into an Angular test component?